# Why aren't my graphics showing?

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

I'm an amateur java coder and I want to make a game similar to SpaceInvaders.

I was wondering why is my frame is blank when I attempt to add my paintComponent Graphic via a panel but when I add my code regularly it shows all results?

Here's my objects class when the graphics are added without a panel and there is no conflict:

```
package SS;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.*;
public class objects extends JPanel{
private int rand1, rand2, y;
int x=0;
Random rand = new Random();
public class picture extends JPanel{
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    for (int c=0;c<=1000;c++){
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        rand1=rand.nextInt(1920);
        rand2=rand.nextInt(720);
        g.drawOval(rand1, rand2, 1, 1);}
    g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    g.fillRect(1920/2-x,720-100+y, 50, 50);
        }
    }
}
```

Now this version of my objects class produces a blank frame

```
package SS;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.*;
public class objects extends JPanel{
private int rand1, rand2, y;
int x=0;
Random rand = new Random();
public objects(){
    JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    picture p = new picture();
    jp.add(p);
}
public class picture extends JPanel{
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    for (int c=0;c<=1000;c++){
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        rand1=rand.nextInt(1920);
        rand2=rand.nextInt(720);
        g.drawOval(rand1, rand2, 1, 1);}
    g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    g.fillRect(1920/2-x,720-100+y, 50, 50);
        }
    }
}
```

My purpose of making an external class around paintComponent is that I can make a component out of it for future key binding.

It's driving me crazy! I searched around this site and I cant find anything! If anyone can tell me the cause and solution I would deeply appreciate it :)

This is my main class by the way

```
package SS;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class mainframe {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame();
        mainFrame.setBounds(0, 0, 1920, 720);
        mainFrame.setResizable(false);
        mainFrame.getContentPane().add(new objects());
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(mainFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I'm open to criticism and proper wording for anything I said in this post.

Just to iterate what I mean:
**I want to add the graphics I made from my paintComponent method to the jpanel listed as jp, then add that jpanel to my frame in the mainFrame class**

Also sorry if my missed anything, this is my first post in StackOverflow.

Comment: I tried to add the code via the textbox format but It did not let me add it so I took screenshots. Sorry!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Posting images of your code is not encouraged as links can end up dead in the future, and it may make them harder to read in general. It would be good if you could post your code in the answer directly using the code blocks.

EDIT: Just saw your comment above. What errors do you get when trying?

Comment: In the future, you must show code as code, not as images. We can't copy images into our IDE's and run them. If the site tells you that the code is too big, then shorten it, but try to make sure that it still compiles and runs for us, a [mcve]. Do go through the how to ask sections of the [help].

Comment: Hello admins, I'm now correcting my errors to the post, and thank you Rome_Leader for the extending hand, but It was just un-clarity of directions to me, which I figured out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second example you are adding `picture` panel to a new `jp` panel in `objects` constructor but that new panel is not added to the `objects` itself. Try to add the following line at the end of `objects` constructor: `this.add(jp);`.

Update on how to specify preferred size:

```
public class picture extends JPanel{

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(500, 500);
            }  
...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The graphics show in the frame, yet as a extremely small square in the middle top of the frame. If I would need further assistance I'll post it. Again, thank you very much!

Comment: Since you are adding custom paint logic to your `picture` panel and are not adding any other Swing components the layout manager does not know how big your panel needs to be made. Try to override the `getPreferredSize` and specify the size you want it to have. See my updated answer.

Comment: Hello, I have tried this and it seems to fix my solution. Thank you so much!